# How to remove Blooger post snippet code from below template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, google-blogger-api

Here is the demo link of the Blogger theme I will be using : https://shareme-templatesyard.blogspot.com/ and here are I posted full Template code https://pastebin.com/n13RQGnC

I don't have my own blog yet. I have tried to remove `<data:post.snippet/>` in order to show full posts instead of snippets, but I couldn't find it for this specific template. I'm not a coder, so any help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to show full posts on the homepage?
If yes, do the following:

Go to Theme > Edit HTML
click "Jump to Widget"
select "Blog1"
locate & find this line `<b:includable id='postBodySnippet' var='post'> .. </b:includable>`
Replace the entire line to below...

```
<b:includable id='postBodySnippet' var='post'>
<div class='container post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-snippet-&quot; + data:post.id'>
<data:post.body/>   </div> </b:includable>
```

click Save Theme
Refresh your blog page to see the changes.

In addition you may want to remove the "**Read More**" link at Contempo homepage or index pages, here's how:-

1. Go to Theme > Customize
2. select Advanced
3. find & select
4. Add CSS add below:-

   ```
   .jump-link {
     display:none;}
   ```